# How can I focus the onclick onto this icon? (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with figuring out how to focus the 'clicking' part of this dropdown navbar icon so that I don't have to click a little to the left of the icon (also the other navbar items) since I'm trying to recreate Mac OS's navbar.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-power-off"></i>
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

IMG:
[image: the dropdown only opens when you click a couple of pixels to the left of the icon]

Comment: Could you clarify or give an image of wanted behaviour as I am not quite sure what you want to achieve. 
Also you gave incomplete html and css so we can't really reconstruct your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

I found the [source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) where OP came from and I am not surprised why you ran into trouble. W3Schools is a good resource because it's simple and never over explains things but at times it omits or just overlooks certain details. In the W3School example [*"Dropdown Menu Inside a Navigation Bar"*](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click) the following segment of a CSS ruleset is wrong:

```css
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

`focus` event only applies to the these tags:

- `<input>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<select>`
- `<a>`

It may vary between browsers but the above list is standard. So `<button>` is *usually not* focusable.

### Solution

- Change the `<button>` into an `<a>`
- Add `e.preventDefault();` to the event handler so the page won't jump when the `<a>` is clicked.

The rest of the changes are recommended, but not necessary. Although I strongly suggest that you don't use inline event handlers:

```html
<button onclick="lame(this)">Don't do this</button>
```

Instead use:

```js
// onevent property
document.querySelector('button').onclick = better;
```

OR

```js
// event listener
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', best);
```

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("menu");

document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = toggleMenu;

function toggleMenu(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menu.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.btn, .btn *') && menu.classList.contains('show')) {
    menu.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2vmax/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  min-width: 7.75rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.2rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.btn * {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.btn i {
  padding-top: 0.15rem;
}

nav a:hover,
.btn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 7.75rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

menu a {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.2rem;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}

menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <a href='#' class="btn"><b>Menu</b>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <menu>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </menu>
  </div>
</nav>
```